# Moving a robot on a specific path

Tags: prolog

Supose I have a grid like this one(I don't know the size of the grid)

```
(-1,1)  (0,1)  (1,1)
(-1,0)  (0,0)  (1,0)
(-1,-1) (0,-1) (1,-1)
```

In this grid are N boxes. I want to write some predicates in order to move the robot in every cell of the grid and check if there is a box or not. It is important not to miss a cell because I don't know where the boxes are.

First of all I have this predicate

```
init([N,0,0])

N - number of boxex to discover
0,0 - my initial position
```

The predicates that handle the moves of the robot have got this structure

```
perform(+ProgramData, +ContainsBox, -Action, -ProgramDataUpdated)

perform([N,X,Y], false, move(west), [N,NX,Y]):- NX is X - 1, !
perform([N,X,Y],false, move(east), [N,NX,Y]):- NX is X + 1, !
perform([N,X,Y], false, move(north), [N,X,NY]):- NY is Y + 1, !
perform([N,X,Y], false, move(south), [N,X,NY]):- NY is Y - 1, !
```

If a box is in a cell I have this predicate:

```
discovered([N,X,Y],true,discovered,[NN,X,Y]):-NN is N-1,!.
```

If I have discovered N boxes my program ends and I have this predicate:

```
done([0,_,_],_,done,[0,_,_]).
```

I don't know how to make sure that I don't miss any cell of the grid

Comment: Provide sample input and output that you want to get.

Comment: Start by defining your sequence of moves as a Prolog list: `[(0,1), (-1,1), ...]` and define your predicate to operate on that. As @GrzegorzAdamKowalski is saying, you need to be a bit more  specific on what it is you want for inputs and outputs. But I would suppose a list like I'm suggesting would be a logical input.